# Why doesn't d_ delete to the first non-blank character on the line?

Tags: normal-mode, operator

v^ and v_ both select to the first non-blank character on the line.

d^ deletes to the first non-blank character on the line, but d_ deletes the entire line.

Why is this? Is there any reason to use it over dd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_` is a **linewise** motion operator (`:h linewise`), its primary purpose is to move your cursor to `<count> - 1` lines below your current position.

For example:
`5_` will move your cursor 4 lines down

The motion to the beginning of the line is just a side effect of that move. So when you type `d_`, the delete operation is applied from the current line to `0` lines below the current line. Result is, the current line gets deleted.

`^` is a **characterwise** motion operator (`:h characterwise`), that's why it doesn't delete the whole line.

In that case, since the visual mode doesn't change the text, you don't see the **linewise** / **characterwise** difference.

I don't think `d_` has any difference with `dd` in terms of performances or behavior, you can use one or the other.

Comment: _ is mostly there for operators that dont provide the “hit twice for a line”—handy in custom maps/operators